# Is it possible for garbage collected languages to have direct memory acccess?

Tags: memory-management, garbage-collection, malloc

Is it possible for garbage collected languages to have direct memory acccess?

For instance, I want to show something like this

```c
void crash(){
  for(int i=0; i<1000000; i++){malloc(42)};
}
```

will incur no problems in a garbage collected language, but I'm not sure what the way to go about showing that is.

Comment: C# does, though there are very specific semantics involving the `unsafe` keyword to ensure programmers are explicit when using that feature.

Comment: You can also pin a managed memory block in .NET so it can be accessed by unmanaged code without risk of it moving. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/interop/copying-and-pinning

Comment: What do you mean with “direct memory access”? Your example program does not contain any memory access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short: yes.

---

I'll use java as an example.
For a long while you could access off-heap memory by using `sun.misc.Unsafe` though this was frowned upon and accompanied by dire warnings that it would go away at some time.

One easier way is to use `DirectByteBuffer` which uses off-heap memory.

Java is moving on with new, more endorsed ways of accessing off-heap memory, JEP-370 (https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/370) and JEP-383 (https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/383).

Comment: So, does using these off-heap memory get garbage collected after use? `unsafe` seems to suggest that we do have to free it ourselves.

Comment: It kind of depends on how you mean. Yes, you have to administer the memory yourself. Garbage collection is only applicable to the heap and you're not using memory on the heap. But, if you are using DirectByteBuffer, then the non-heap memory will be released on garbage collection.